# Positioning an unordered list in ROR

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, css-float, html-lists

I have the following list that I'm trying to display in a Rails app. I want to display each user's image, then list each of their "pins" inline next to them, descending by rank. I can't seem to get the right CSS coded to display each user on a separate row. Each next user floats left against the previous list. Here is my code:

```
 <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <ul  class="ver2"> 
        <li><div><%= link_to (image_tag user.image(:small)), user %><h3><%= user.name %></h3></div></li> 
        <% user.pins.order('rank DESC').each do |pin| %>
            <% if pin.date == 2013 %> 
              <li><div class="square"><%= link_to (image_tag pin.image(:medium)), pin %><br/> #<%= pin.rank %> -  <%= truncate(pin.album, length:20) %> - <%= pin.artist %> -</div></li>
            <% end %>
        <% end %> 
    </ul>   
<% end %>
```

CSS:

```
.ver2 li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
}
.ver2 img {
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
}
.square {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Does <%= link_to (image_tag user.image(:small)), user %> generate an <img> or <a><img></a>?

Could you please get rid of the ruby code? 




It is completely irrelevant to this CSS issue. Copy the generated HTML from the frontend and paste it here. Thanks.

Comment: Is this your current generated markup? http://jsfiddle.net/bxK7t/

Comment: Yes, thanks Mark. @thargor had what I needed with clear: left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a clear: left on the .ver li element.